# Как вывести значение в указанном формате?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Имеется таблица с данными, внутри таблицы есть поле `date(DATETIME)`.

Как вывести это значение в указанном формате?

Пытался вот так, выдает ошибку:

```
echo '<td>'.date("m.d.y",$row->date_one).'</td>';
```

Comment: echo'<td>'.date("m.d.y",$row->date_one).'</td>'; пытался вот так, выдает ошибку

Comment: сделайте var_dump($row->date_one). Скорее всего, там текстовый формат. Ща на него глянем и подскажем

Answer (score 1):

Ну а пока вы смотрите :), напишу свое предположение

то, что вы получаете из базы данных имеет, скорее всего, текстовый формат `2015-07-12 12:05:00`. Поэтому стоит сделать так

```
$str = '2015-07-12 12:05:00';
echo date('c', strtotime($str)); // 2015-07-12T12:05:00+00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Выводите из базы сразу отформатированное нужное значение.
Например:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(поле с датой, '%Y-%m-%d') AS mydate FROM таблица
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать класс [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php).

```
$date = new DateTime($row->date_one);
echo '<td>' . $date->format('m.d.y') . '</td>';
```